# Custom WordPress post query for displaying time-released content on website

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to implement a "content drip-style/time released content" subscription system using a WordPress query that filters and selects content from a custom post type using set parameters and displays them on a page template. The initial parameters for the query and how the retailers (pages) and posts are structured are included below.

```
<?php
/**
 * Pages that are defined as 'Retailers'.
 * Each retailer (page) will have a defined start date using an Advanced Custom Fields date picker field. This field is set manually by the site admin.

 * The retailer pages will display a defined number of posts from the 'sendouts' custom post type in a HTML dropdown (explained below).
 * The number of displayed posts is handled in part by the start date parameter.
 * A new post will be added every 14 days (2 weeks).

 * EXAMPLE 1: Retailer A has a start date of January 1, 2019. Counting up from that start date to the current date (January 7, 2020),
 * the retailer will have a total of 26 posts accessible from the HTML dropdown.

 * EXAMPLE 2: Retailer B has a start date of December 1, 2019. Counting up from that start date to the current date (January 7, 2020,
 * the retailer will have a total 2 posts accessible from the HTML dropdown.

 * EXAMPLE 3: Retailer C has a start date of January 1, 2020. As the start date is less than 14 days (two weeks) old, only one post will be displayed
 * and the HTML dropdown will not be displayed on the page.
 * 
*/

// Advanced Custom Fields date picker field assigned to each Retailer page
$startDate = get_field( 'sendout_start_date' );

// Set the timezone to America/Edmonton to localize date to region
date_default_timezone_set( 'America/Edmonton' );

// Grab the current date for the set timezone
$currentDate = date( 'm/d/Y h:i:s a', time() );

// Add fourteen days to the current date
// Use this variable in a loop to increment the total number of visible posts by one every 14 days
$datePlusFourteen = date_add( $currentDate, new DateInterval( 'P14D' ) );

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'sendouts', // Select posts from the 'sendouts' custom post type
    'cat' => '101', // Make sure they are assigned to the 'Sendout' category
    'post_per_page' => $totalPosts, // Define a variable that contains the total number of posts to display in the HTML dropdown
    'order' => 'ASC', // Display the posts in ascending order
    'orderby' => 'p' // Order by post ID
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

The query needs to be expanded to include the following parameters:

- If retailer page created date is on the current date (today), select the oldest post from the custom post type and display it on the page. Only the oldest post should be displayed. After a 14 day (2 week) period, display the second oldest post on the page and move the oldest post into a dropdown/HTML select that will use AJAX to dynamically navigate between posts. I have the AJAX filtering functionality mostly working, I just need to figure out how to properly define the WP query.

Retailer pages and send out items structure:

**Current date (today): December 28, 2019**

Send out items:

- Send out item one
- Send out item two
- Send out item three

**Retailer A (page)**

- Start date: December 1, 2019
- Dropdown should contain three recent send out items. Selecting an item would initiate an AJAX call and dynamically replace the post displayed on the page.

  - Send out item one (December 1)
  - Send out item two (December 15)
  - Send out item three (January 1)

**Retailer B (page)**

- Start date: December 15, 2019
- Dropdown should contain two recent send out items. Selecting an item would initiate an AJAX call and dynamically replace the post displayed on the page.

  - Send out item one (December 15)
  - Send out item two (January 1)

**Retailer C (page)**

- Start date: January 1, 2020
- Dropdown should not appear as the start date for the page matches the current date. After January 15, the dropdown will appear and be populated with the send out item one. An additional send out item will be added to the dropdown every 14 days (2 weeks).